# Select a single result from groups by the min of two values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | meta1 | meta2   | value1 | value2 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | foo   | bar     |    0.1 |   0.01 |
|  1 | baz   | quux    |    0.2 |   0.01 |
|  1 | lorem | ipsum   |    0.1 |   0.05 |
|  2 | dolor | sit     |    0.2 |   0.02 |
|  2 | amet  | eos     |    0.3 |   0.02 |
|  3 | clita | corpora |    0.5 |   0.03 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

I am trying to extract one (complete) row for each id with the lowest `value1` and in the case that there are equal `value1`s, falling back to the lowest value2.

The query should result in a result set like this:

```
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | meta1 | meta2   | value1 | VALUE2 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | foo   | bar     |    0.1 |   0.01 |
|  2 | dolor | sit     |    0.2 |   0.02 |
|  3 | clita | corpora |    0.5 |   0.03 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

I started by attempting the following query:

```
SELECT
    t1.*
FROM
    test t1
        INNER JOIN
    (SELECT
        id, MIN(value1) minValue1
    FROM
        test
    GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
        AND t1.value1 = t2.minValue1;
```

But this doesn't 'break the tie' for id '1' and I end up with two of those records. I have tried adding HAVING clauses and additional subqueries and am lost beyond this initial step. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want all records for which no better record (ie. with lower value1 or same value1 and lower value2) exists:

```
select *
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable better
  where better.id = mytable.id
  and 
  (
    better.value1 < mytable.value1
    or 
    (better.value1 = mytable.value1 and better.value2 < mytable.value2)
  )
);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for and was unable to express.

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that if both values are tied only one result is returned in the final output?

Comment: @JerrySmithwell Which one?

Comment: In the cast of two rows where the id, value1, and value2 are the same, i just want the first row. (or any one of the two)

Comment: @JerrySmithwell I don't know if mysql allows the use of rownum.
 If so, then you can try:
 
 better.value1 < mytable.value1
    or 
    (better.value1 = mytable.value1 and better.value2 < mytable.value2)
    or 
    (better.value1 = mytable.value1 and better.value2 = mytable.value2 and better.rownum < mytable.rownum)

Comment: By "first", do you mean the first alphabetically?

Comment: @JerrySmithwell I think you can avoid two rows using this (selecting the minimum meta1 if both values are tied):
 
select *
from mytable
where not exists
(
  select *
  from mytable better
  where better.id = mytable.id
  and 
  (
    better.value1 < mytable.value1
    or 
    (better.value1 = mytable.value1 and better.value2 < mytable.value2)
  )
)
group by value1, value2
having meta1 = min(  meta1 ) ;

Comment: Simply add one more criteria to the WHERE clause, about as Egl suggests in his/her first comment: `or (better.value1 = mytable.value1 and better.value2 = mytable.value2 and better.meta1 < mytable.meta1)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `not exists`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM test t2
                  WHERE t2.id = t.id AND
                        (t2.value1 < t.value1 OR
                         (t2.value1 = t.value1 and t2.value2 < t.value2) )
                 );
```

An alternative method is to use variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (@rn := if(@i = id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@i := id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from test t cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @i := -1) params
      order by id, value1, value2
     ) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,meta1 VARCHAR(12)
,meta2 VARCHAR(12)
,value1 DECIMAL(5,2)
,value2 DECIMAL(5,2)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1 ,'foo','bar',0.1,0.09),
(1 ,'baz','quux',0.2,0.08),
(1 ,'lorem','ipsum',0.1,0.07),
(2 ,'dolor','sit',0.2,0.06),
(2 ,'amet','eos',0.3,0.05),
(3 ,'clita','corpora',0.5,0.04);

SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT x.id
            , x.value1
            , MIN(x.value2) min_value2  
         FROM my_table x 
         JOIN 
            ( SELECT id
                   , MIN(value1) min_value1 
                FROM my_table 
               GROUP  
                  BY id
            ) y 
           ON y.id = x.id 
          AND y.min_value1 = x.value1
        GROUP 
           BY x.id
            , x.value1
     ) b
    ON b.id = a.id 
   AND b.value1 = a.value1
   AND b.min_value2 = a.value2;

+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | meta1 | meta2   | value1 | value2 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|  1 | lorem | ipsum   |   0.10 |   0.07 |
|  2 | dolor | sit     |   0.20 |   0.06 |
|  3 | clita | corpora |   0.50 |   0.04 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```

you can extend this indefinitely, but at some point an laternative solution may become easier to manage...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL
,meta1 VARCHAR(12)
,meta2 VARCHAR(12)
,value1 DECIMAL(5,2)
,value2 DECIMAL(5,2)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1 ,'foo'  ,'bar'    ,0.1,0.09),
(1 ,'baz'  ,'quux'   ,0.2,0.08),
(1 ,'lorem','ipsum'  ,0.1,0.07),
(2 ,'dolor','sit'    ,0.2,0.06),
(2 ,'amet' ,'eos'    ,0.3,0.05),
(3 ,'clita','corpora',0.5,0.04),
(1 ,'bar'  ,'foo'    ,0.1,0.07);

SELECT a.*
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN 
     ( 
     SELECT q.id 
          , q.value1
          , q.value2
          , MIN(q.meta1) min_meta1
       FROM my_table q
       JOIN 
          (
             SELECT x.id
                  , x.value1
                  , MIN(x.value2) min_value2  
               FROM my_table x 
               JOIN 
                  ( SELECT id
                         , MIN(value1) min_value1 
                      FROM my_table 
                     GROUP  
                        BY id
                  ) y 
                 ON y.id = x.id 
                AND y.min_value1 = x.value1
              GROUP 
                 BY x.id
                  , x.value1
          ) r
         ON r.id = q.id
        AND r.value1 = q.value1
        AND r.min_value2 = q.value2
      GROUP 
         BY q.id
          , q.value1
          , q.value2
      ) b
    ON b.id = a.id 
   AND b.value1 = a.value1
   AND b.value2 = a.value2
   AND b.min_meta1 = a.meta1;

+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
| id | meta1 | meta2   | value1 | value2 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
|  2 | dolor | sit     |   0.20 |   0.06 |
|  3 | clita | corpora |   0.50 |   0.04 |
|  1 | bar   | foo     |   0.10 |   0.07 |
+----+-------+---------+--------+--------+
```